# Why Reactjs is displaying all the Users Fullname at a time

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display each user's record based on user's button click.

The Checking condition is that if Users status is true display result on button click. If False remove result on button click.

Here is my issue, if just click on just one user, instead of displaying that users particular **fullname**, it will just display all the **fullname** of all the users. I think the Id of the Users is conflicting.

I need to get user's fullname displayed for that user one after another based on Id.

**Here is the code**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      arr: [],
    };
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      arr: [
    {   userid:1, username: "user1", fullname: "James Moon",    Status: false},
    {   userid:2, username: "user2", fullname: "Bebeto Carlos", Status: false},
    {   userid:3, username: "user3", fullname: "John snow",     Status: false},
    {   userid:4, username: "user4", fullname: "Michael Owen",  Status: false}
      ]
    });

  }


// Check if Users status is true display result on button click. If False remove result on button click.
checkUserStatus = (id) => {
//checkUserStatus = function(id) {

if (this.state.arr[0].Status == true) {
    this.state.arr[0].Status = false;
 this.setState({checkstate: this.state.arr[0].Status});

    } else {
     this.state.arr[0].Status = true;
 this.setState({checkstate: this.state.arr[0].Status});
    }
  }



  render() {
const {id} = this.state;
    return (
      <span>
        <label>
          <ul>


            {this.state.arr.map((user, index) => (
           
<li key={index} onClick={() => this.checkUserStatus(this, index)}>
                {user.username}
                <br />

              </li>
            ))}




{this.state.arr.map((stat, index) => {

//this.state.arr.filter();
//this.state.arr.find();

if (this.state.checkstate == true) {

          return (
            <div key={index}>
       <div  >       
 {stat.Status}: {stat.fullname} 
            </div>
              </div>
          )


  }
        })}

          </ul>
        </label>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: are you looking for a solution like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-akpylk ?

Comment: Yes Sir Jayavel, you are getting it. When one click user, it displays users fullname which means the status is true.  On another click of the same User, fullname should disappear which means that the status is false. Thanks for helping me out. I cannot wait to see your update on answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my understanding, you need to do this : When a user is clicked, the fullname will be displayed and when the user clicks again on the same element, the fullname will be hidden. Is this you need, the below procedure is have to be followed.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      arr: [],
    };
  }
   componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      arr: [
        {   userid:1, username: "user1", fullname: "James Moon",    Status: false},
        {   userid:2, username: "user2", fullname: "Bebeto Carlos", Status: false},
        {   userid:3, username: "user3", fullname: "John snow",     Status: false},
        {   userid:4, username: "user4", fullname: "Michael Owen",  Status: false}
      ]
    });

  }

checkUserStatus = (e) => {
  const id = e.target.dataset.id;
  let arrClone = this.state.arr.map(item => ({...item}) ); 
  arrClone.filter(ele => ele.userid === parseInt(id) ? ele.Status =  ele.Status ? !ele.Status : true :  ele.Status = false)
  this.setState({ arr: arrClone });
}


 render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <label>
          <ul>
            {this.state.arr.map((user, index) => (
              <li key={user.userid} data-id={user.userid} onClick={this.checkUserStatus}>
                {user.username}
                <br />
              </li>
            ))}
            {this.state.arr.map((stat, index) => {
              return (
                stat.Status ? // show only status true item
                <div key={index}>
                    <div  >       
                        <span> {stat.username}: {stat.fullname} </span>
                </div>
                  </div> : null
              )
            })}
          </ul>
        </label>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

[demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-akpylk) Hope this helps.

Comment: Am sorry for being late. Thanks so much Mr Jayavel. That is exactly  I want. You really solve my problem. Please I need one request from  you though its not part of the question. When I click on the first user, its fullname gets displayed and I can Hide it also that is great but when I click on another user, users the fullname overlaps the first one. If I click on Eg. three users one by one, am supposed to be seeing three different fullname that corresponds to each user. Please can you help further.Your answer is still the best hoping to hear from you soon. Between thanks

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

As I under stand that you want to display full name of user for which user you click the button.

For this you can create one function to handle current user.

```
   this.state = {
          currentUser: {
            fullname:''
                       }
            };
```

you can modify this

```
    {this.state.arr.map((user, index) => (
<li key={index} onClick={() => this.handleCurrentUser(this, user)}>
                {user.username}
                <br />
              </li>
            ))}
```

After that create a function

```
handleCurrentUser(this, user) {
    this.state.currentUser = user;
    this.setState({currentUser: this.state.currentUser})
}
```

Now you can render using

```
     return (
            <div key={index}>
       <div  >       
 {this.state.currentUser.fullname} 
            </div>
              </div>
          )
```

Hope this helps.